# How can I exclude a directory from ls command

Tags: linux, unix

Let say we have

```
Scripts
Test 
Test1
```

When we do `ls` it shows all the three directories but I need to exclude the `test1`.
So I should get only

```
Scripts
Test
```

What command should I use here to exclude a directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`ls -ITest1`

from `man ls`:

```
  -I, --ignore=PATTERN
          do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN
```

You can use it multiple times like:

`ls -ITest1 -ITest2`

or you could use a matching pattern:

`ls -ITest?`

Comment: How about excluding multiple directories tried ls -I dir1 di2 didn't work ?

Comment: you can also use a list such as {item1,item2,item3}. That gives you ls -I{a,b,c,d,e,f}

Comment: What if you want to ignore all sub directories and files, but not a directory itself?  For example showing the `build` directory or the `.git` directory, but ignoring its contents (when used with `-R`)

Comment: @Tarek didn't say this, but this works when your list contains **two** or more items, separated by a comma.

Comment: Needs a space delimiter between `-I Test1`.

Comment: That's funny cause i'm looking at `man` for `ls` on macOS and it describes the parameter `-I` as:

`-I  Prevent -A from being automatically set for the super-user. This option is not defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (“POSIX.1”).`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this via `grep -v`. Command will be `ls /mydir/ | grep -v 'test1'`

The `-v` means exclude.

Good references here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/

Comment: Thank you guys  how about multiple directories exclusion ?   I tried ls | grep -v dir1 dir2 but didn't work

Comment: You can use egrep (grep with a logical OR) like this `egrep -v 'dir1|dir2|dir3'` use `|` to seperate the directories

Answer (score 4):

Try these:

```
ls -la | egrep -v ^d
```

-or-

```
ls -p | egrep -v /$
```

-or-

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: 2 was the one! TKS